# How to verify that I have upgraded to the new backend storage?

Tags: baking

According to Protocol 006_PsCARTHA Carthage documentation:

> The baking daemon requires direct access to the context of the Tezos
>   node. The daemon for 006 requires the new context introduced by
>   Irmin2. As such bakers that use the default baker need to upgrade to
>   the new storage backend in order to be able to run the 006 baking
>   daemons.

Would /.tezos-node/version.json/0.0.4 indicate that I am running the upgraded storage version?

Referenced:

http://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/006_carthage.html#baking-daemon

Answer (score 5):

Yes, version.json 0.0.4 is correct
You can start the 006 baker and endorser now and run them side-by-side with 005.  006 will auto start at the right time and 005 will auto-stop.

Comment: Thank you much!

Comment: @Jovi1945 please mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

After updating your binaries, you can run `./tezos-node upgrade storage --status` to check if a storage upgrade is available on your node.